# Simplify IQueryable Linq to SQL query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Below I present to you an IQueryable LINQ to SQL query (used with NHibernate).
I have tried to simplify this query but I could not do it.
I want to run a query for searching information.

Options:

1. search on source or target
2. search with match case or not
3. search match exact or not

The query it seems to work but there is much if/else branching.

Is it possible to simplify it?

```
        if (concordanceSearchOptions.SearchInSource)
        {
            if (concordanceSearchOptions.MatchCase)
            {
                if (concordanceSearchOptions.MatchExact)
                {
                    getByQueryable = getByQueryable.Where(p => p.SourceSegment.Equals(concordanceSearchOptions.SearchText));
                }
                else
                {
                    getByQueryable = getByQueryable.Where(p => p.SourceSegment.Contains(concordanceSearchOptions.SearchText));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (concordanceSearchOptions.MatchExact)
                {
                    getByQueryable = getByQueryable.Where(p => p.SourceSegment.ToLower().Equals(concordanceSearchOptions.SearchText.ToLower()));
                }
                else
                {
                    getByQueryable = getByQueryable.Where(p => p.SourceSegment.ToLower().Contains(concordanceSearchOptions.SearchText.ToLower()));
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (concordanceSearchOptions.MatchCase)
            {
                if (concordanceSearchOptions.MatchExact)
                {
                    getByQueryable = getByQueryable.Where(p => p.TargetSegment.Equals(concordanceSearchOptions.SearchText));
                }
                else
                {
                    getByQueryable = getByQueryable.Where(p => p.TargetSegment.Contains(concordanceSearchOptions.SearchText));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (concordanceSearchOptions.MatchExact)
                {
                    getByQueryable = getByQueryable.Where(p => p.TargetSegment.ToLower().Equals(concordanceSearchOptions.SearchText.ToLower()));
                }
                else
                {
                    getByQueryable = getByQueryable.Where(p => p.TargetSegment.ToLower().Contains(concordanceSearchOptions.SearchText.ToLower()));
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Naming**

Based on the [naming guidlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) variables/fields should be named "using a noun, noun phrase, or adjective". So `getByQuerable` should be renamed to something following the guidlines and also meaningful.

**Optimization**

- you should extract the searching for `Source` and `Target` to separate methods. This helps for readability and makes it easier for **Mr.Maintainer** in a couple of months.
- preparing the searchtext before the actual search takes place will speed up the query.
  Right now if `concordanceSearchOptions.MatchCase == false` you call for each source/target in the where part the `ToLower()` method of the `SearchText` property.

**Refactoring**

```
    String searchText = concordanceSearchOptions.SearchText;
    if (concordanceSearchOptions.MatchCase)
    {
        searchText = searchText.ToLower();
    }

    if (concordanceSearchOptions.SearchInSource)
    { 
        getByQueryable  = GetBySource(concordanceSearchOptions, searchText);
    }
    else
    {
        getByQueryable  = GetByTarget(concordanceSearchOptions, searchText);
    }


private IEnumerable<T> GetBySource(SearchOptions concordanceSearchOptions,String searchText){

}
private IEnumerable<T> GetByTarget(SearchOptions concordanceSearchOptions,String searchText){

}
```

Comment: I do have to execute ToLower inside GetBySource and GetByTarget methods. I don't feel that I have gain so much.

Comment: You don't have to execute `concordanceSearchOptions.SearchText.ToLower()` everytime. Your methods are doing one thing only (SRP), one calls a query on source the other calls a query on target.

Comment: I am referring to the p.SourceSegment.ToLower() or p.TargetSegment.ToLower(). I have to branch the behavior in the GetByTarget/GetBySource. Also

Comment: Also, I have to maintain now two more methods...

Comment: That is right. But there seems to be no way arround.

Comment: Also, the concordanceSearchOptions.SearchText.ToLower() is calculated only once. Since, always run one time in runtime in any codepath.

Comment: That is not true. The code is calling `p.SourceSegment.ToLower().Contains(concordanceSearchOptions.SearchText.ToLower())` for each p.

Comment: You are right. I will make the performance from your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: `Also, I have to maintain now two more methods` this is right, but the methods will be much smaller and more focused and therefor easier to maintain.